# Define range Area as an Object but want it as a Range

Tags: vba, excel

My knowledge of VBA is minimal so its possible (and I hope) a simple problem.

I wish for my code to look at a range and then depending on the values of the cells within the range to highlight the adjacent cells. In my posted code the problem is reduced since I am only looking at a range of 3 cells. In reality the amount of cells I am look at is greater than 500 (so simply using If statements without the loop would be tedious).

To do this I have used a loop and created a dictionary so that I end up with rangeArea(1), rangeArea(2) etc...
I think though because my rangeArea(i) is defined as an object that I can't then get it to select a range and is therefore incompatible with Set multipleRange = Union( and I end up with the message Object required. However if I change rangeArea to a range it then says type mismatch.

What I want it to do is once it has found all the cells that contain the value I want that it should then select all of the adjacent cells as one entity (which is why I used Set multipleRange = Union()

```
Sub Macro()

Dim i As Integer
Dim rangeArea As Object
Dim multipleRange As Range
Dim a As String
Set rangeArea = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

i = 1
Do Until i = 4
    If Cells(i, 1) = True Then
    Cells(i, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:B1").Select
    Set rangeArea(i) = Selection
    Else
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop

    Set multipleRange = Union(rangeArea(1), rangeArea(2))

End Sub
```

I think i'm almost there so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you? Don't think you need a Dictionary, although I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve. You can build up a range using union, and loop through the areas subsequently if necessary.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim i As Long
Dim rangeArea As Range
Dim multipleRange As Range
Dim a As String

For i = 1 To 4
    If Cells(i, 1) = True Then
        If multipleRange Is Nothing Then
            Set multipleRange = Cells(i, 2).Resize(, 2)
        Else
            Set multipleRange = Union(multipleRange, Cells(i, 2).Resize(, 2))
        End If
    End If
Next i

multipleRange.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: the `=True` is not needed if all you want is to build up a range union, but the OP had that condition and I'll assume that's why SJR kept it.

Comment: You are fantastic

Comment: Also If you wish to know I'm trying to select certain areas on my worksheet so that I can easily print them (by choosing print selected areas)

Comment: Glad it worked.  Note though that you don't need to Select anything. @QHarr - omitting the =True does make a difference, any number satisfies the condition.

Comment: Aha. Thanks :-)

Comment: Regarding the `= True` - there is a difference between `Cells(i,1)` and `Cells(i,1).Value`.  When you run the `= True` comparison, it automatically treats that as a `Cells(i,1).Value = True` test.  It's like asking "What is the car?" vs "What **colour** is the car?".  You *might* get the right answer for the first one, but you might get "convertible" or "rear-wheel drive" depending on what the person you are asking *thinks* you are after

Comment: @Chronocidal - just did a test and I can't see any difference if using Value. The difference arises between using `If Cells(i, 1) = True` and `If Cells(i, 1)` which surprised me somewhat.